# Distribute content button during uploading app store

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, app-store-connect, ipa

I have cloned iOS app target, to create one for development and another for production.

Now i have a problem with uploading build to iTunes connect. i am using Xcode 10.1, when archiving finished, "distribute content" button is appeared instead of distribute app.

if i set NO to "skip install" option in Build Settings, problem will gone, but i know that there should be better way to solve the problem.

I think this problem is related to Cocoapod so i will share my pod file

```
use_frameworks!

def my_pods
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
    #...
end

target 'target1' do
    my_pods
end

target 'target2' do
    my_pods
end
```

Have you any suggestions to check my project settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Both targets were added in Edit schemes->Build section, this cause to build both targets same time so Xcode generated content and not IPA.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen when there is other content in the package as well. Had similar problem when in the package ended up also headers files from c++ shared library. Removing those files helped. In this specific case it was about moving some public headers to private section.

Comment: This was my problem, thank you.  I had used 'copy files' to put headers from various static libraries in a shared directory so I only had to have one search path.  Turns out that 'copy files' doesn't just copy files during build phase on your local disc, it also packages them into your build and then this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Making sure to have below Build Settings resolved issue for me :

- "Skip Install" should always be **No** for all Application Targets.
- "Skip Install" should always be **Yes** for all other targets(Includes
  AppClip, Frameworks, Watch Targets).

[Framework Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZcCk.png)